# How to find what view is being used in Code Igniter based on the URI

Tags: codeigniter, routes, view

I am new to Codeigniter and I just inherited a website where the views, controllers, and models are not named consistently with the URIs. For example: mysite.com/about-us might be called our-bio.php in the views folder.

The config/routes.php does not appear to be customised so I'm not sure where the slugs for his pages are coming from.

How am i supposed to know what to edit based on a page's URI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Example

> ```
> - application
>   - controllers
>     - About_us.php
>   - config
>     - routes.php
> ```

The `default controller` is only used when there are no URL segments. It only calls one method, and the default method of a controller is `index()`.

- **Based on uri you can find which `controller` is in use and what `method`, as long as there is no routing, if its routed you will have to see either routes.php or your .htaccess file**
- **Once you know which method is being called, you can see which view is loaded, that is from `$this->load->view('view_file',....,....)`**

Generally, the first part of your URL maps to a controller:

This would invoke the index method of the contact controller:

```
http://yoursite.com/about_us
                      ^
                    controller
```

This would invoke the what_we_do method of the about_us controller:

```
http://yoursite.com/about_us/what_we_do
                     ^           ^
                  controller    method
```

This would invoke the `what_we_do method` of the `about_us controller` and passes `india` as the first argument:

```
 http://yoursite.com/about_us/what_we_do/india
```

[Read all about it in the user guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html)

[Routing](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html)

Comment: You have no clue how much head-ache you just saved me.  Thanks.

Comment: It happens sometimes don't worry :)